# Key binding? (c ) (converting string to function)

Tags: c++, windows, string, casting, keyboard

I am writing a simple keybinding for my application. So far I have 2 arrays (bool m_keys[256], string m_functions).

This is my input class (in input.h)

```
class InputClass
{
public:

InputClass(){};
InputClass(const InputClass&){};
~InputClass(){};

void Initialize(){
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
            m_keys[i] = false;
    functions[i] = "";
    }
}

bool AddFunc(unsigned int key, string func, bool overide)
{
      if((functions[key] == "") || (overide)){
      //overide is used to overide the current string (if there is one)
          functions[key] = func; 
          return true;
      } 
      return false;
    };

void KeyDown(unsigned int input){m_keys[input] = true;};

void KeyUp(unsigned int input){m_keys[input] = false;};

string IsKeyDown(unsigned int key){return m_keys[key] ? functions[key] : "";};

private:
    bool m_keys[256];
    string functions[256];
};
```

In my WinARM.cpp:

In my init function

```
    INIT(m_Input, InputClass) //#define INIT(o,c) if(!(o = new c))return false;
    m_Input->Initialize();
    m_Input->AddFunc(VK_RETURN,"m_Graphics->ToggleWireFrame",true);
```

In my frame function (ran every frame ;)

```
short SystemClass::Frame()
{
string func;
func = m_Input->IsKeyDown(VK_RETURN); //checks to see if the enter key is down
if(func !="") (func as function)(); // <-- this is the code i need help with
if(m_Input->IsKeyDown(VK_F2)!="")m_Graphics->ToggleWireFrame();
if(!m_Graphics->Frame()) return -1;
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please remove all these `;` after the function definitions and indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get a callable function from a string. C++ lacks [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), so doing so really isn't feasible. There's a few alternatives you could use.

My suggestion would be to make your `InputClass::functions` array contain function pointers, instead of strings. You could then pass a function address to `AddFunc` instead of the string and set the given array member accordingly. This will work fairly well for non-member functions. If you want to be able to call member functions of class instances, I would make `InputClass::functions` be an array of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)s and pass the functors returned by [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) into `AddFunc`.

Comment: That, or if using the string name is important just create and (manually) maintain a mapping of valid names to function pointers using `std::map`.

Comment: Use `std::map` instead of that dangerous array in any case.  I'd either use `std::function<void(SystemClass*)>` or `std::function<void()>`, depending on how dependencies work in your code.